# What is wrong with this sentence? "Hello, may I have some water to my tomatos please?"

Tags: grammar

"Hello, may I have some water to my tomatos please?"

Context: I am eating some tomatos and am thirsty, so I am ordering (a glass of) water.

Teacher said it's wrong, but wasn't able to explain any further than "its not right". I feel this is something people would understand.

Comment: You just want some water. Why mention the `tomatoes`? (spelling). They are not relevant.

Comment: The waiter might suppose you wanted to pour the water over the tomatoes. You want a glass of water, you ask for a glass of water. Imagine: you have a burger and some fries. You want some ketchup. You just ask for ketchup. The waiter doesn't care what you do with it. Whether you want to put it on the fries, the burger as well, or just make a little pool on the side of the plate, doesn't matter.

Comment: Plural of "tomato" is "tomatoes". As had been mentioned by 
Michael Harvey, you just ask for water, no need to mention tomatoes. If you were having some salty food, and you are choosing to mention the salty food—you may say, "Hello, may I have some water [to go with] my salty food – please?" it would sound natural. If you say "Hello, may I have some water [to go with] my tomatoes – please?", it would sound unnatural or unusual.

Comment: You can sure ask to *have some water **with** my tomatoes*. It would be strange to have to ask, though, since water usually comes even before you've ordered anything. Since *with* is the usual preposition, if you use *to*, that will be taken as meaning something else.

Comment: @banuyayi - in general, we do not need to explain why we want water with our food. The staff don't care.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty - Not here - in the UK you normally have to ask for tap water at the table (but of course it's taken for granted that it's to drink with your meal!).

Answer (score 1):

The particular mistake is the use of the preposition "to".  This preposition has a wide range of meanings, but the central meaning is "in the direction of"  You don't want water "in the direction of" the tomatoes!  You want some water "on the side of" the tomatoes, and the correct preposition is "with".

You would probably mean "some water *with* my tomatoes".

However, in a restaurant context, you don't need to tell the staff what you are eating, or why you want some water, so the most natural thing to say would simply be

> May I have some water?